# Update SQL from Checkbox in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listview, checkbox

**Goal**: Update row(s) in SQL table when Checkbox inside ListView is clicked.
I would like to update the following columns from sql: 
IsApproved
ApprovalType

I am able to find the checkbox in the row that is clicked from the Listview on the page. However, that is as far as I got. Current code below, as well as what I've tried and the subsequent errors.

---

**Code**:

**aspx**:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lstUsers" runat="server" ItemType="Program.Data.Table" DataKeyNames="ID" SelectMethod="lstUsers_GetData"
    OnItemCommand="lstUsers_ItemCommand" DeleteMethod="lstUsers_DeleteItem" OnSorting="lstUsers_Sorting"
    OnItemDataBound="lstUsers_ItemDataBound"
    ItemPlaceholderID="litPlaceHolder" >

<LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>                            
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>UserName</th>
                       <th>Approve User</th>
```

```
            <td><%# Item.LastName %></td>
            <td><%# Item.FirstName %></td>
            <td><%# Item.UserName %></td>
            <td> <asp:CheckBox ID="cbApproved" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Approve_Click" /> </td>
```

**c#**:

```
protected void Approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lstUsers.Items)
        {
            if ((item.FindControl("cbApproved") as CheckBox).Checked == true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("it was checked!");
```

I've tried:

- item.ColumnName   -- but get error *ListView does not contain a
  definition for ''*
- item.DataItem  -- the output displays what looks
  like an object as a whole
  *(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewDataItem)*
- item.DataItem.ColumnName
  -- but get error *Object does not contain a definition for ''*

Do the column values im looking to update in SQL have to be displayed on the ASPX page?

I looked through:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx#ModifyingDataUsingTheListViewControl

[Asp.Net CheckBoxList to update a SqlDataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192207/asp-net-checkboxlist-to-update-a-sqldatasource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what is currently working for me. Too long to add in comment or clutter original post:

ASPX:

```
  <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("UserName") %>' /></td>
                <td> <asp:CheckBox ID="Approved" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Approve_Click" /> </td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Changed the ItemTemplate to use asp Label controls so I could reference them in the code behind:

```
protected void Approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listUsers.Items)
            {
                if ((item.FindControl("Approved") as CheckBox).Checked == true)
                {
                    Label myLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("UserNameLabel");
                    try
                        {
                            IQueryable<SUR> user = null;
                            user = db.SURs.Where(m => !m.IsApproved && m.UserName == myLabel.Text);

                            if(user != null)
                            {                                   
                                db.sp_SUA(user.FirstOrDefault().ID, SessionMgr.CurrentUserID.ToString(), "Manual");
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
                        }

                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

Once getting the control that had the username, I check if the DB has a row with the same value
If so, use a stored procedure to update the DB

**EDIT:**

After refactoring, I was wondering if it would be more efficient to get rid of the foreach loop, and instead use the OnItemCommand property of ListView and set the OnCheckedChanged for the Checkbox to point to the ItemCommand method? My thinking is since I am not looping through each item, would having the array index be better in terms of Big O?

Code would be:

```
protected void listSTUFF_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    if (int.TryParse(list.DataKeys[e.Item.DisplayIndex].Value.ToString(), out id)) {
        var myQuery = db.Table.Where(a=>a.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        db.StoredProcedure(myQuery.ID)
        db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @VDWWD Any thoughts on the "EDIT" above? Replacing foreach with OnItemCommand?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply cast the sender to a CheckBox?

```
protected void Approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as CheckBox).Checked == true)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("it was checked!");
    }
}
```

You must bind data to the ListView inside an `IsPostBack` check for it to work.

UPDATE

What you want can be done easily with DataKeyNames. Add it to the ListView as a property.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="IDColumn">
```

Then when the checkbox is changed read the correct key

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        ListView1.DataSource = Common.fillBooks();
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Approve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to the checkbox
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        //get the parent of the parent (itemtemplate > listiew)
        ListView lv = cb.Parent.Parent as ListView;

        //get the dataitem from the namingcontainer
        ListViewDataItem item = cb.NamingContainer as ListViewDataItem;

        //get the correct datakey with the index of the dataitem
        int ID = Convert.ToInt32(lv.DataKeys[item.DataItemIndex].Values[0]);

        //update database here with the ID
    }
}
```

ListView

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" ItemType="Namespace.Class">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbApproved" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Approve_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: My WriteLine is printing to Output. That part is fine, the question is more centered on once we are inside the if statement, how do I update the row in SQL associated with the row where they clicked the checkbox (every row has a checkbox, but I only care about the row the user clicked and HOW to update the associated SQL data)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had DataKeyNames already. I should have included it, just updated my code. Using your updated solution I'm getting a NullReference error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' lv was null. " ..This makes me think if lv is null that cb must be null? Which means its not recognizing sender?

Comment: Strange, because I can assure you it works. See my complete example. Are you sure you implememt the code correctly? What happens if you use just my code, do you still get a nullreference?

Comment: I had commented out mine and pasted yours. 

The only thing that would be different would be the         ListView1.DataSource = Common.fillBooks();

What is Common.fillBooks() ?

Comment: `Common.fillBooks();` is just some method for generating dummy data that I use for testing...

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't able to get that working for some reason but it gave me some ideas. I have a solution that is working now, I posted above